# How to add delays between shadow-cljs auto builds

Tags: shadow-cljs

#### Context

I am using shadow-cljs in the clojurescript (react-native) project.
And for triggering UI rerender I am using `:before-load-async` and `:afterload` lifecycle hooks. The reagent atom is used as the key for screens and in `:afterload` event this key is bumped to trigger re-rendering.

I also added a locking mechanism to make sure two rerendering don't get triggered at once.

#### Problem

As several screens and components are getting rerendered, it sometimes takes some time (2-3 sec). If in the meantime I modify any related file and trigger a rebuild, the app crashes with  `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 24537`.

(Note: Issue don't happen always, some time needs to quickly edit and save the file 7- 8 times, for timing the collision)

#### Things I tried

I tried adding a significant delay(20 sec) for blocking a call to `:afterload` to make sure we are not bumping the reagent atom before the first rerender completes.

#### Possible Cause

While we are forcing rerender to old hot reloaded code, code changes due to another build and breaks forced render

#### Possible Solution

I can control the UI part with the help of locking and async hooks but I am not sure how can I delay auto hot reloading.
Either, there should be a config parameter to add delays between autobuilds or I should able to stop auto builds in `:before-load-async` and resume in the `:afterload` hook. But as `shadow.cljs.devtools.api` is a clj file I am not able to call `(shadow.cljs.devtools.api/watch-set-autobuild! :app false)` in cljs

Related code: https://github.com/Parveshdhull/status-mobile/commit/2c505fd01f4d5b11dc9509f9bb18fabf355ed222

Crash log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zhymiED1o7rpTsmpwbwQ_xOVPRMu64Ug/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I guess best thing I can do for now is create my own save-buffer function for emacs, which makes sure that there are at least a few seconds gap between the two files saved. This way build will not be triggered while UI is rendering old changes.